# Overnight, I open my phone to find an unknown app running since android 12 upgrade

Tags: android-12

I'm running a Pixel 3A.
After the last upgrade to Android 12, I regularly find that an app is active in the background overnight.

Its logo is 2-dimensional, and consists of dark green ball floating above green heart. The heart has three shades of green and is constructed out of a square with semicircles to the left and right.
If I try to navigate to it, it minimizes,
If I swipe away it disappears.

Does anyone know what this is?
here it is:

[image: logo of app]

Comment: A google image search doesn't find anything either

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.wellbeing

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Irfan, It is Digital Wellbeing, albeit well hidden.

For others who have this problem, some notes:

- I'm surprised that google images doesn't locate it, but there you go.
- It does not appear in the app drawer (see image below) - you can only get to the app via settings.
- In my case, it seems to be activated when the phone is in bedtime mode
- When you click it, it doesn't take you to the wellbeing screen, it just
  minimizes itself. That is very disconcerting.

My app drawer image:[image]